# Why are page components getting bumped to bottom of components list after template is deployed?

Tags: content-editor, presentation, templates, deployment, components

After a particular template is deployed during a release, page level components are getting bumped to the bottom of the components list on page final layout. We've pulled that template from getting deployed so this has stopped happening, but the next time we need to deploy that template it's going to cause the same issue.

For example:

### Page final layout BEFORE release:

TemplateLevelComponentA
**PageLevelComponentB**
TemplateLevelComponentC

### Page final layout AFTER release:

TemplateLevelComponentA
TemplateLevelComponentC
**PageLevelComponentB**

Also, not sure if this is related but the shared layout on the template contains only components from base templates, the final layout contains components for the page (plus the components from shared).  I'm learning not everyone has their templates set up this way.

Comment: You would need to provide more details on what the deployment is doing.

Comment: Hi Michael--I tweaked my post to make it a little more clear.  Thanks!

Comment: @ecorry Does the source where the template you are deploying has the correct order on the presentation details? For example, if you are packaging the item from Local to install on Production, does the version on the local instance in proper order?

Comment: Hi Hishaam--Yes, the installed template has the same version and the same order as production.  Thanks!

Comment: This template does not have any inheritance that contains a rendering on it?

Comment: The template does inherit from a base template with a rendering.  I'll definitely look into that.  However, the issue described above occurred over and over after releases for months.  (The content team kept fixing the component order on pages without reporting it.)  The base template is rarely touched and when it is, people are careful to check it into the code base.

Comment: Can you share the raw values of the Shared and Final layout of the template where you are getting packaging it and the same for the template on the deployed env